# C++ - Multilevel Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, multi-level

I am new to C++ and this is the first time I am learning about inheritance. I have some confusion regarding multilevel inheritance which I wanted to discuss.

Consider this code:

```cpp
class Parent 
{
  ...
  virtual void foo() {...} // virtual function
  ...
}
class Child
  : public Parent
{
  ...
  virtual void foo() override {...} // 1
  ...
}
Class GrandChild
  : public Child
{
  ...
  void foo() override {...} // 2
  ...
}
```

Now,

1. I know that `1` overrides `Parent` class method.
2. But, I am not sure about `2`. Which method does it override, the one in `Parent` or the one in `Child`?

Kindly, correct me if I am wrong. Also, if there are any useful articles regarding this please refer them to me.

Comment: it would be easier if you show real code. In particluar it is not clear what you mean in 4. With the code as posted it is not possible to see any effect. Also please one question per quesiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the class `GrandChild` here overrides the `Child` method. However, it's not a very useful distinction, as `GrandChild` inherits from both `Child` and `Parent` (indirectly). Therefore, you could do all of the following:

```cpp
int main() {
    Parent* p1 = new Child();
    p1->foo(); // calls Child::foo

    Parent* p2 = new GrandChild();
    p2->foo(); // calls GrandChild::foo

    Child* c = new GrandChild();
    c->foo();  // calls GrandChild::foo

    // cleanup all of the pointers
}
```

Comment: What if I change the declaration in the `Child` class to `void foo() override {...}`? What will `Child::foo()` mean for the `GrandChild` class.

Comment: Nothing--whatever the type of the *actual instance* is, that's which method will be called. That counts as long as the topmost class has `virtual` in its signature: all derived methods with the same name are automatically `virtual`. In fact, using `override` would give you an error if it weren't `virtual`.